# How to break line in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that contains a lot of `div`s in a line. I want it so that when there are too many `div`s on the line, the other `div`s are shown in a new line.
The problem can be seen in this image:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: use css to control the width of the main div and take note on Display property. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Hard to give you an exact answer without seeing your current HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use *flexbox* with these settings on your container element:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex:
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inline-block` CSS property:

```
.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Read more about this property here: [Inline-Block - LearnLayout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)